# Как в JavaScript создать экземпляр класса на имени?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Доброго времени суток.
Возник у меня вопрос, как создать объект, имея имя класса в переменной? Есть ли аналогичная возможность, как та, что реализована в php:

```
$className = 'MyClass';
$newObj = new $className();
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

---

По наводке @Other сделал так:

```js
    "use strict";

    class Maxy {
      constructor() {
        this.Name = undefined;
      }
      Render() {
        console.log('Rendering...')
      }
    }

    let Maxies = {
      Mini1: class extends Maxy {

      },
      Mini2: class extends Maxy {

      },
      Mini3: class extends Maxy {

      }
    };

    function CreateMini(Type) {
      let Mini = new Maxies[Type];
      return Mini.Render();
    }

    console.log(CreateMini('Mini2'));
```

Comment: [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классы, как и `const`, и `let`, не создают свойств в глобальном объекте, так что найти их по имени в переменной не выйдет.
Использование `eval` *может* помочь, но всем знакомо правило: **Don't use eval!**.

---

Можно специально создать свойство (или набросать простой плагин для `Babel`, который сам это будет делать):

```js
window.Test = class Test{
  notify(){
    console.info('Yeah!');
  }
}

let name = 'Test',
    app  = new window[name];

app.notify();
```

Но, если честно, я не придумаю ситуации, где это нужно, ведь `Enum`-структуры нужно хранить в контейнере:

```js
let np = {
  app: class{
    notify(){
      console.info('Yeah!');
    }
  }
};

let name = 'app',
    app  = new np[name];

app.notify();
```

Comment: Спасибо, @Other! Не знаю, на какие грабли я наступлю в будущем, но пока реализовал свою задумку на 2-ом примере. С eval() не получилось, т.к. она возвращает функцию, а не объект (ну или я как-то не так ее использовал), а window мне не подходит, т.к. пишу код для серверной части с использованием node.js.

Comment: @proudbird, пожалуйста, спасибо тут выражаются плюсом и, если решилось, принятием ответа (галочка слева). `eval` не зря так похожа на `evil` :) `window` - это глобальный объект в браузере, `global` - примерный аналог для ноды.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  myName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

window.User = User;

const a = 'User';
const b = new window[a]('Name');

b.myName();
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, @DimenSi, но я забыл упомянуть о том, что пишу для серверной части, а там нет объекта window.

Comment: Global в node.js

Comment: да, через global тоже получилось, но через массив с классами мне больше понравилось - как минимум, не нужно добавлять кучу дополнительных свойств с global, типа 'global.class1 = class1; global.class2 = class2...'

Answer (score 0):

Все гениальное просто. Попробуйте:

```js
var CLASSES = {}
CLASSES.myClass = class myClass extends ... {
....
}

var object = new CLASSES.myClass(args)
....
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]